# Create a CSV table with name and ID from local HTML file using Python

Tags: python, html

I'm a newbie trying to practice using Python to get data from a local HTML file to extract name and ID to save as a table in CSV file.
The HTML is as follow:

```
<td>
  <a href="https:............" data_id="45498" class="roster_user_name 
......
<span name="Clarence Alan" src="
</a>
    
</td>

<td>
  
    88889999
  
</td>
```

My code to have the name list:

```
all_urls = [a['name']
for a in soup('span')
if a.has_attr('name')]

good_urls = list(set(all_urls))
print(len(good_urls))
good_urls
```

I don't know how to extract the ID ('88889999') and combine them into a 2-column table.

I am very new to Python.
Thank you for who answer for this.

Comment: Do you see `<tr> ... </tr>` enclosing that HTML code and repeats for each row? (Like: `<tr> <td>name</td> <td> 5756 </td> </tr>`?

Comment: Yes, I see them, 137 </tr>, the same amount with my entry list.
</tr><tr class="
 <div id=
</td>
<td>
  <a href="

</a>
  
  
</td>


<td>
  
    66526260
  
</td>

Answer (score 0):

I asked you if the HTML has `<tr>` tags and your reply show that number of tr tags equals the number of entries you want to scrape.

Using beautifulsoup, you can loop through all tr tags, and for each tr tag you can extract the required information.

**Example** (replace first parameter in BeautifulSoup to html string)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<html> </html>', 'html.parser')
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    name = row.find_all('td')[0].text
    number = row.find_all('td')[1].text
```

This should loop through all rows and get name and number.

Then you could you `CSV` library to store the data.

**Example**

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["COL1", "COL2"])
```